# can't mount WD MyPassport usb drive on Ubuntu (or windows)

Tags: ubuntu, usb, hard-disk

I have not used this drive in over a year, and now cannot get it to mount.  It shows up under lsusb:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1058:0748 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport (WDBKXH, WDBY8L)
```

but does not show up among the other disks when I use `$ sudo fdisk -l`

```
$ dmesg shows:
[539237.155146] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[539237.249128] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=0748
[539237.249139] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[539237.249146] usb 2-1.1: Product: My Passport 0748
[539237.249152] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[539237.249158] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 575835314135333837353632
[539237.250183] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[539237.251781] scsi host9: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[539238.261343] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 0748 1022 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[539238.261893] scsi 9:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1022 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[539238.265797] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[539238.265963] ses 9:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[539238.266078] ses 9:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
[539246.274415] ses 9:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 0
[539246.274441] ses 9:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0xffffffea
[539246.274460] ses 9:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[539246.283206] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[539247.294850] .........................not responding...
[539451.305699] sd 9:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[539631.372661] sd 9:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[539811.328621] sd 9:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[539811.328667] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[539811.328681] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[539811.328694] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[539991.276581] sd 9:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[539991.276680] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[540171.292931] sd 9:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[540171.292962] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[540171.292968] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[540171.302306] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Unit Not Ready
[540171.302316] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[540171.302322] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Internal target failure
```

Looking for general advice, tools, etc. that could help me recover what's on the drive.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see it in `dmesg`?

Comment: There are hardware errors showing up in `dmesg`. If it also doesn't appear in Windows, then it looks like it's toast. You need to get a new drive.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Nasir Riley there are hardware errors showing up in `dmesg`. Try using it in Windows 10.
You can also try running Drive tests by utilizing [WD Drive Utilities](https://support-en.wd.com/app/products/product-detail/p/250#WD_downloads).

If the drive is in fact dead then you have 2 courses of action in order to save your data.

1. Leave it to the professionals

If there are important files, work documents or anything you can't afford to lose it's best to avoid messing around with the drive. Over at WD website you will find a [complete list](https://support.wdc.com/warranty/datarecovery.aspx) of WD partners ready to help.

2. Do it yourself

If you decide to take the DIY road you will find plenty in-depth tutorials online but be careful.